# Add quotes to each column in a CSV via Powershell

Tags: powershell, csv, export-to-csv

I am trying to create a Powershell script which wraps quotes around each columns of the file on export to CSV. However the Export-CSV applet only places these where they are needed, i.e. where the text has a space or similar within it. 
I have tried to use the following to wrap the quotes on each line but it ends up wrapping three quotes on each column.

```
$r.SURNAME =  '"'+$r.SURNAME+'"';
```

Is anyone able to share how to forces these on each column of the file - so far I can just find info on stripping these out.

Thanks

Comment: In my experience with PowerShell 4, when you pass a file through `Import-CSV` and then export it back out with `Export-CSV`, it always adds double quote field identifiers for every field.  It might be silly, but after your initial export, running `Import-Csv $file | Export-Csv $file -NoTypeInformation -Force` might fix the quoting issue for you automatically.

Comment: This still only leaves the quotes around the values with spaces or other special characters. It does look like I have access only to Powershell V1 which may be part of the the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use the following code:

```
$r.SURNAME = "`"$($r.SURNAME)`""
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps a better approach would be to simply convert to CSV (not export) and then a simple regex expression could add the quotes then pipe it out to file.

Assuming you are exporting the whole object `$r`:

```powershell
$r | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation `
   | % { $_ -replace ',(.*?),',',"$1",' } `
   | Select -Skip 1 | Set-Content C:\temp\file.csv
```

The `Select -Skip 1` removes the header. If you want the header just take it out.

To clarify what the regex expression is doing:

Match: `,(.*?),`

Explanation: This will match section of each line that has a comma followed by any number of characters (`.*`) without being greedy (`?` : basically means it will only match the minimum number of characters that is needed to complete the match) and the finally is ended with a comma. The parenthesis will hold everything between the two commas in a match variable to be used later in the replace.

Replace: `,"$1",`

Explanation: The `$1` holds the match between the two parenthesis mention above in the match. I am surrounding it with quotes and re-adding the commas since I matched on those as well they must be replaced or they are simply consumed. Please note, that while the match portion of the `-replace` can have double quotes without an issue, the replace section must be surrounded in single quotes or the `$1` gets interpreted by PowerShell as a PowerShell variable and not a match variable.

Comment: What if there is a comma in the text? How does this address the first and last column?

Comment: Well obviously the only way a comma can exist inside a CSV is if the string containing the comma is already wrapped in quotes. So you could change the match expression to only match on fields that do not have quotes. Something like this: `',^"(.*?)^",'` . As for the first and last columns, you could write a super complicated regex expression to handle it all or just send the results of the first replace into another replace that handles specifically the first and last columns.

Comment: Note, I had originally written this code in order to remove quotes as I needed them gone, which of course is a much simpler regex expression. The point I was trying to make is that you don't **have** to use `Export-Csv` and just accept the way it does things. You can use `ConvertTo-Csv` and then use regex to modify it to your hearts content.

Comment: ConvertTo-Csv does not appear in the version (v1) of Powershell I have access to. My original file does have the quotes in the right places but the initial aim of the script was to transform a date stamp which it does but on exporting I lose the quote marks.

Comment: I've modified your regex to allow for values already quoted, so that it doesn't double quote.  
  
     `| % { $_ -replace ',\"?(.+?)\"?,', ',"$1",' }`

Answer (score 0):

I have cheated to get what I want by re-parsing the file through the following - guess that it acts as a simple find and replace on the file.

```
get-content C:\Data\Downloads\file2.csv 
| foreach-object { $_ -replace '"""' ,'"'} 
| set-content C:\Data\Downloads\file3.csv
```

Thanks for the help on this.